# How do you write generic and type-safe functions in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Disclaimer: I come from a OO language background (mostly C++), so please take this into account when going over my question.

I have several tables which all have a `timestamp` column in common. Now I want to create a function which in a type-safe manner creates a JSON object which holds the `min` and `max` of certain rows belonging to these tables.

Writing these functions in an ad-hoc, repetitive manner for each table is quite easy. But this repeats code. This leads me to my question. How do you write such functions as elegant and generic as possible (while being type safe, that is, without constructing queries manually)?

In pseudo-code, I am looking for something like the following:

```
create function get_min_max(rows of tables which have timestamp colmn) returns json as $$
    select json_build_object('min', min(timestamp), 'max', max(timestamp))
    from $1;
$$ end;

select get_min_max(select * from my_table where some_condition);
```

Comment: Your object-oriented instincts are not going to help you very much as you learn SQL.  You need to think more in terms of dataflows and data processing.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I get that. I am trying to shift my thinking and this question is an example in an area I have problems with. I need to do the same kind of logic for several tables, but I cannot find a generic approach.

Comment: Type safety doesn't exist in SQL in any meaningful sense. This is a job for an ORM.

Comment: With type safety I meant: you could write a function which concats several string to construct a query. This would work, but looks ugly (imho).

Comment: Good design patterns in relational databases rely on the fact that you know the schema beforehand. "Generic" means that it does works for anything you don't know. The paradigms go in opposite directions. There must be one function per table in SQL, or create the queries dynamically in client-side code.

Comment: Also, "DRY" concepts don't really apply in SQL. Repetition is often completely necessary. Unless we're talking the design of the schema itself.

Comment: @Alejandro One function per table...in this case I am just doing `min` and `max`, but imagine the logic is more complex. This means I am duplicating complex logic for each table function? How can this every be maintainable (honest question)?

Comment: If the entire purpose of the db is to store unrelated json objects, perhaps noSQL is what you really want?

Comment: I am constructing JSON documents for relational data (REST API). I am testing the waters if constructing JSON documents could be done in pure SQL functions instead of doing these constructions/conversions in my backend service as you would traditionally do.

Comment: @Samuel It can't be maintainable :P, As you've noted, that's just craziness when complexity goes beyond a few tables. My point being, SQL is not a language for using anything "generic", but to deal with specific and known data structures. You don't have some features you take for granted from OO languages, like inheritance, interfaces, generics and the like.

Comment: Too bad, I really hoped we could do some more advanced stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom aggregate.

```
create or replace function timestamp_agg_function(jsonb, timestamp)
returns jsonb language plpgsql as $$
declare
    result jsonb;
begin
    if $1 is null then
        return jsonb_build_object('min', $2, 'max', $2);
    elseif $2 > ($1->>'max')::timestamp then
        return $1 || jsonb_build_object('max', $2);
    elsif $2 < ($1->>'min')::timestamp then
        return $1 || jsonb_build_object('min', $2);
    else
        return $1;
    end if;
end $$;

create aggregate timestamp_agg(timestamp) (
    sfunc = timestamp_agg_function,
    stype = jsonb);
```

Example usage:

```
with my_table(tstamp) as (
values
    ('2018-03-20'),
    ('2018-03-10'),
    ('2018-03-30')
)

select timestamp_agg(tstamp::timestamp)
from my_table;

                        timestamp_agg                         
--------------------------------------------------------------
 {"max": "2018-03-30T00:00:00", "min": "2018-03-10T00:00:00"}
(1 row)
```

Read more in the documentation: [User-defined Aggregates](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xaggr.html) and [CREATE AGGREGATE.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createaggregate.html)

Comment: That's quite interesting. I did not realize you could create such custom aggregates!